# Running c or c++ code in standalone Xcode playground

Tags: c++, c, swift, swift-playground

I would like to create a standalone playground and just drop a bunch of swift code into the Sources folder. I also have dependency on c/c++ code, so I also dropped those, and added a Bridging Header.

These bunch of files compiled together in an Xcode project. However, i can't get them to work as a standalone Playground. Note that I aint trying to write c in the playground, but Swift code that in terms are wrapper for that C.

Any idea how thats done? if possible.

Note: Not sure why my Q is voted down. It is legit. Again, I plan to write Swift code in playground, but need a 3rd party library that has C files in it.

Answer (score 1):

Playgrounds are Swift only.

What I do when I'm experimenting with language subtleties is to use a Mac command-line tool. It doesn't have a UI, and doesn't have the overhead of launching the simulator. Command line tools can be in any combination of supported languages.

Obviously this wouldn't help if the code you are working on is iOS specific, but there's actually quite a bit of overlap in the Foundation and Core Foundation frameworks.

### Edit:

If what you have is a third party library, you should be able to build it into a Cocoa framework and include that in your playground. See this link for more (somewhat out of date) information: https://pardel.dev/2018/08/10/3rd-party-frameworks-in-xcode-playgrounds/

Comment: To clarify, I aint testing c or c++ code directly in my playground. In fact, I am testing a 3rd party library that has c code in it. In Xcode, you would use a bridging header. In playground, all i want for it is to compile. All further testing are done with swift.

Comment: See the edit to my answer.